# VMWare ESX 4.1 Settings Disappear on Reboot

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere

I have two different VMWare ESX servers where upon rebooting the server all of the settings disappeared. In both cases this was after rebooting to enable VT technology. Also in both cases, rebooting again didn't cause any problems.

The settings that disappeared include:

- Management Interface Settings
- The License (Reset it to a 60 day trial)
- Password

The VMs are still on the data store however. Anyone had this problem before, if they have, were they able to resolve it?

Comment: Possibly related: I had two guests lose their network configuration after shutting them down and putting the host into maintenance mode in vSphere 4.1

Comment: I lost all my config after putting into maintenance mode too

Answer (score 2):

This covers that issue:
http://communities.vmware.com/message/1710379
updated iso fixes the issue.